# Is there a way to catch off dom bubble with jquery?

Tags: jquery, oop, object, event-handling, event-bubbling

Is there a way to catch event bubbling of custom events without dom connection.

```
function b() { 
  $(this).trigger("b"); 
  return this
}

function a() { 
   this.Test = function() {
      new b()
   }; 
   return this
}

var o = new a()
$(o).on("b",function(){console.log("o")})

o.Test() // no bubbling
```

Comment: There is no custom event code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Event()` object to create new events:

```
var ev = new Event("look", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
document.dispatchEvent(ev); // the event bubbles and can't be cancelled
```

[Src @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the solution that I'm looking for, since it uses the "document" Dom as the dispatcher. I've created a solution and would appriciate any comments on it:https://jsfiddle.net/shaibam/fndys0Lm/

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, though I am sure that there is a better way to do it (since I've used the a Dom elemnt that isnt on the document)

```
//Non Dom Objects 
function NonDomJqueryObj(type) {
    var T = this;
    T.dom = $("<o></o>");
    T.Obj = eval("new "+type+"()");
    return T;
}

NonDomJqueryObj.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
    this.dom.append(child.dom);
}

NonDomJqueryObj.prototype.Dispatch =function(event_name,args) {
    if (!args)
        $(this.dom).trigger(event_name);
    else 
        $(this.dom).trigger(event_name,args);
}

NonDomJqueryObj.prototype.Listen =function(event_name,callback) {
    $(this.dom).on(event_name,callback);
}

//some object costructor
function test() {
    var T = this;
    return T;
}

var child1 = new NonDomJqueryObj("test");
var child2 = new NonDomJqueryObj("test");
child1.addChild(child2);

var parent1 = new NonDomJqueryObj("test");
parent1.addChild(child1);

parent1.Listen("FIRST_EVENT",function(e,e_p) {
    console.log(e_p)
    console.log("FIRST_EVENT caught");
    $("p").html($("p").html()+"<br>"+e_p+"<br>FIRST_EVENT caught")
})

child1.Dispatch("FIRST_EVENT","from child1");
child2.Dispatch("FIRST_EVENT","from child2");
```